# when I draw a polygonWithHole the circle isn't in right position

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

[image]I want draw a polygon with hole , my method is draw poly first and then draw circles and then group them, the result is it works but the circle isn't in right position.here are my functions(this is draw polygon)

```js
/**
 * Created by XJ on 2017/9/13.
 */
var polyWithHole=false;
var polyWithHoleMode=false;
var polyWithHoleGroup;
prototypefabric.polyWithHole = {
    drawPolyWithHole : function() {
        polyWithHoleMode = true;
        pointArray = new Array();
        lineArray = new Array();
        activeLine;
    },
    addPoint : function(options) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        var id = new Date().getTime() + random;
        var circle = new fabric.Circle({
            radius: 5,
            fill: '#ffffff',
            stroke: '#333333',
            strokeWidth: 0.5,
            left: (options.e.layerX/canvas.getZoom()),
            top: (options.e.layerY/canvas.getZoom()),
            selectable: false,
            hasBorders: false,
            hasControls: false,
            originX:'center',
            originY:'center',
            id:id
        });
        if(pointArray.length == 0){
            circle.set({
                fill:'red'
            })
        }
        var points = [(options.e.layerX/canvas.getZoom()),(options.e.layerY/canvas.getZoom()),(options.e.layerX/canvas.getZoom()),(options.e.layerY/canvas.getZoom())];
        line = new fabric.Line(points, {
            strokeWidth: 2,
            fill: '#999999',
            stroke: '#999999',
            class:'line',
            originX:'center',
            originY:'center',
            selectable: false,
            hasBorders: false,
            hasControls: false,
            evented: false
        });

        if(activeShape){
            var pos = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
            var points = activeShape.get("points");
            //console.log(points+"Lpointsin")
            points.push({
                x: pos.x,
                y: pos.y
            });
            var polygon = new fabric.Polygon(points,{
                stroke:'#333333',
                strokeWidth:1,
                fill: '#cccccc',
                opacity: 0.1,
                selectable: false,
                hasBorders: false,
                hasControls: false,
                evented: false
            });
            canvas.remove(activeShape);
            canvas.add(polygon);
            activeShape = polygon;
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
        else{
            var polyPoint = [{x:(options.e.layerX/canvas.getZoom()),y:(options.e.layerY/canvas.getZoom())}];
            var polygon = new fabric.Polygon(polyPoint,{
                stroke:'#333333',
                strokeWidth:1,
                fill: '#cccccc',
                opacity: 0.1,
                selectable: false,
                hasBorders: false,
                hasControls: false,
                evented: false
            });
            activeShape = polygon;
            canvas.add(polygon);
        }
        activeLine = line;
        pointArray.push(circle);
        lineArray.push(line);

        canvas.add(line);
        canvas.add(circle);
        canvas.selection = false;
    },
    generatePolyWithHole : function(pointArray){
        var points = new Array();
        $.each(pointArray,function(index,point){
            points.push({
                x:point.left,
                y:point.top
            });
            canvas.remove(point);
        });
        $.each(lineArray,function(index,line){
            canvas.remove(line);
        });
        canvas.remove(activeShape).remove(activeLine);
        var polygon = new fabric.Polygon(points,{
            stroke:'#333333',
            strokeWidth:0.5,
            fill: '#ccc',
            opacity: 1,
            selectable: false,
            hasBorders: false,
            hasControls: false
        });

        polyWithHoleGroup=new fabric.Group([polygon ],{
            //stroke:'#333333',
            //strokeWidth:0.5,
            //fill: 'red',
            //opacity: 1,
            //selectable: false,
            //hasBorders: false,
            //hasControls: false
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center'
            //left:'left',
            //top:'top'
        });
        polyWithHoleGroupLeft=polyWithHoleGroup.left;
        polyWithHoleGroupTop=polyWithHoleGroup.top;
        //console.log(polyWithHoleGroup.left+";"+polyWithHoleGroup.top)
        canvas.add(polyWithHoleGroup);

        polygonMode=false;
        activeLine = null;
        activeShape = null;
        polyWithHoleMode = false;  //stop draw PolyWithHole
        polyWithHole=true;  //add C and P
    }

};
```

```js
/**
 * Created by XJ on 2017/9/11.
 */
var circle,origX,origY;
var addPolyWithHole=false;
prototypefabric.circle={
    drawCircle:function(){
        circleMode=true;
    },
    addCenterPoint:function(options){
        var pointer=canvas.getPointer(options.e);
        console.log(pointer.x);
        origX=pointer.x;
        origY=pointer.y;
        circle= new fabric.Circle({
            radius: 1,
            fill: '',
            stroke: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            left: pointer.x,
            top: pointer.y,
            originX:'center',
            originY:'center',
            selectable: false,
            hasBorders: false,
            hasControls: false
        });
        canvas.add(circle);

    },
    generateCircle:function(options){
        var pointer=canvas.getPointer(options.e);
        var R=Calculate.lineLength(origX,origY,pointer.x,pointer.y).toFixed(2);
        text=new fabric.Text('Radius'+R+'('+origX.toFixed(2)+','+origY.toFixed(2)+')',{left:pointer.x,top:pointer.y,fontSize:12,hasBorders: false,
            hasControls: false});
        canvas.add(text);

        if(polyWithHole || addPolyWithHole){
            circle.set({
                radius:Calculate.lineLength(origX,origY,pointer.x,pointer.y).toFixed(2),
                selectable: true,
                hasBorders: false,
                hasControls: false,
                strokeWidth: 0,
                fill:'yellow',
                originX: 'center',
                originY: 'center',
                left:pointer.x,
                top:pointer.y
                //left:options.e.layerX/canvas.getZoom(),
                //top:options.e.layerY/canvas.getZoom()
            });
            polyWithHole=false;
            addPolyWithHole=true;
        }
        else{
            circle.set({
                radius:Calculate.lineLength(origX,origY,pointer.x,pointer.y).toFixed(2),
                selectable: true,
                hasBorders: false,
                hasControls: false
        });
        }
        polyWithHoleGroup.add(circle);
        console.log(polyWithHoleGroup.getObjects());
        if(polyWithHole || addPolyWithHole){ canvas.remove(circle);}
        canvas.selection = true;
    }

}


/**
 * Created by XJ on 2017/9/9.
 */

var min = 99;
var max = 999999;
var polygonMode = false;
var lineMode=false;
var circleMode=false;
var arcMode=false;
var pointArray = new Array();
var lineArray = new Array();
var points=new Array();
var activeLine;
var activeShape = false;
var drawStop=false;
var startX, startY;
var moveX,moveY;
//var centerPoint;
var text;
var canvas;
var isCircleDown=false;
var isArcDown=false;
//var setGroupActive=false;
$(function(){
    prototypefabric.initCanvas();
    
    $('.create-polyWithHole').click(function() {
        polygonMode = false;
        lineMode=false;
        circleMode=false;
        arcMode=false;
        prototypefabric.polyWithHole.drawPolyWithHole();
    });
    $('.create-polyWithHole-addC').click(function() {
        polygonMode = false;
        lineMode=false;
        circleMode=false;
        arcMode=false;
        setGroupActive.rSet();
        if(polyWithHole || addPolyWithHole){
            prototypefabric.circle.drawCircle();
        }
    });
   
    
});

var prototypefabric = new function () {
    this.initCanvas = function () {
        canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
        canvas.setWidth($("#mycanvas").width());
        canvas.setHeight($(window).height()-$(".div_header").height()-$(".canvas_header").height()-$(".canvas_footer").height());
        //canvas.selection = false;

        canvas.on('mouse:down', function (options) {
            startX=options.e.x;
            startY=options.e.y;
          
            if(polyWithHoleMode){
                prototypefabric.polyWithHole.addPoint(options);
            }
            if(polyWithHoleMode&&options.target && options.target.id == pointArray[0].id){
                prototypefabric.polyWithHole.generatePolyWithHole(pointArray);
            }
            
            if(circleMode){
                isCircleDown=true;  //if draw C
                prototypefabric.circle.addCenterPoint(options);
            }
            
        });
        canvas.on('mouse:up', function (options) {
            circleMode=false;
            arcMode=false;
            isCircleDown=false;
            isArcDown=false;

        });
        canvas.on('mouse:move', function (options) {
            moveX=options.e.x;
            moveY=options.e.y;
            canvas.remove(text);
            canvas.renderAll();

            if(activeLine && activeLine.class == "line"){
                var pointer = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
                activeLine.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });

                var px=Calculate.lineLength(startX,startY,moveX,moveY).toFixed(2);
                text=new fabric.Text('Length'+px+'('+pointer.x.toFixed(2)+','+pointer.y.toFixed(2)+')',{left:pointer.x,top:pointer.y,fontSize:12});
                canvas.add(text);

                if(polygonMode || polyWithHoleMode){
                    var points = activeShape.get("points");
                    points[pointArray.length] = {
                        x:pointer.x,
                        y:pointer.y
                    };
                    activeShape.set({
                        points: points
                    });
                };
                canvas.renderAll();
            }


            if(circleMode&&isCircleDown){
                prototypefabric.circle.generateCircle(options);
                canvas.renderAll();
                setGroupActive.doSet();
            }
            
            canvas.renderAll();
        });
    };
};
var Calculate={
    lineLength:function(x1,y1,x2,y2){
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1,2)+Math.pow(y2-y1,2))
    }
};
var setGroupActive={
    doSet:function(){
        polyWithHoleGroup.set({
                selectable: true
            })
        console.log("setin?")
    },
    rSet:function(){
        polyWithHoleGroup.set({
                selectable: false,
                originX: 'center',
                originY: 'center'
            })
        console.log("setin?")
    }
}
```

this is draw circle and mouse event ,can anybody tell me how I correct it ,I have no method

Comment: Please include your HTML code or try to put your code in the jsfiddle